# CALayer is not clear when drawing

Tags: cocoa, calayer

[image]

I use CALayer to make a tab bar.
But sometimes, drawing is not clear as you can see 'index.pgiu'. If I see this on retina display, it is more worse than usual screen. (See difference between 'index.pgiu' and 'Flow' label )

How can I fix it? Even I cannot find keyword for google.

Comment: Maybe caused by anti-aliasing. You might want to draw between pixels and not on pixels. So x.5 instead of x as pixel value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer.

```
[[NSScreen mainScreen] backingScaleFactor]
```

Comment: Like, layer.contentsScale = [[NSScreen mainScreen] backingScaleFactor];

Answer (score 0):

In IOS :

```
self.progressLayer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```